# FuzzyWuzzy or Levenshtein

Tags: python-3.x, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I want to get ratio from matching data, i have large amount of data, and i want using python for matching process. for example : 
I compare combination between name and age

```
Name   Age
Jo     15
Ame    10
Rio    23
Joe    15
```

Comparation will be :

```
Jo15 will be compared with Ame10, Rio23, Joe15 

Ame will be compared with Rio23, Joe15 and so on
```

Which one is better between FuzzyWuzzy and Levenshtein?
or any idea to make the data matching faster?

Comment: it appears to be the same thing https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Comment: if you have a large amount data a cosine similarity coupled with a vectorizer will be much faster and maybe more efficient

Answer (score 0):

FuzzyWuzzy is based on [Levenshtein distance](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/). There's no difference.

Comment: FuzzyWuzzy is based on the indel distance. In contrast to the Levenshtein distance, it does not allow substitutions.

Comment: I've added a link to the documentation that says it uses Levenshtien distance. Substitution is a part of it.

Comment: It is the Levenshtein distance with substitution weight 2. So each substitution is counted as insertion + deletion. This is commonly referred to as Indel distance.